# Altium Designer : How to make a custom Top paste for D2PAK pad

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, pcb-fabrication

I know my way around altium designer but i am not finding a good way to make openings in the solder paste layer for the tab pad of D2pak .

This is what i want :
[image]

Altium only allows me to make the paste increase or decrease in size , but it stays a square , so i cannot make multiple smaller squares as the recommended Stencil.

best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decrease the size of the automatically generated paste feature to zero (by making the paste mask expansion a negative number).

Then add whatever shapes you want to the paste mask layer using the Place Region command.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Remove the existing square and draw your own pattern. Keep in mind the paste mask layer is negative, so wherever you draw the regions, that's where the holes will be in the mask, and thus where the solder will be applied.

Comment: this is correct , i can confirm that it works . Thanks